# Send json object with another parmeter to the controller in spring mvc

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring, jakarta-ee

1.- I want to recive this two paramters like this in my controller :

*/Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insertCatalogGeneric", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    String insertCatalogGeneric(@RequestBody CatalogGeneric catalogGeneric , String tableName) {

        String table_name = tableName;
        String catalogInserted = catalogGenericService.insertCatalogGeneric( table_name, catalogGeneric);

        return catalogInserted;
    }
```

2.- I send to the contoller in this way...

```
$.ajax({
                        url : 'insertCatalogGeneric',
                        type : 'POST',
                        data:  {'catalogGeneric' : JSON.stringify(description_data) , 'tableName' : "fadsf"},
                        async: true,
                        cache: false,


                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
```

3.- In my debug I receive error 400 not found the direction .... i know that is for the way that i send the parameters , but what will be the correct form to do that ?

Comment: Can you post json you are sending and error stacktrace too?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, Ajax call having  contentType: "application/json" format, So when your doing ajax call with  JSON format, In your Controller your Request Mapping should have `consumes = "application/json"`,

For the particular request mapping add like this in your controller,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insertCatalogGeneric", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    consumes = "application/json") 
public @ResponseBody
String insertCatalogGeneric(@RequestBody CatalogGeneric catalogGeneric , String tableName) {
```

Answer (score 0):

[Additional]
For safe request body format
try to stringify the whole JavaScript Object.

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'insertCatalogGeneric',
    type : 'POST',
    data:  JSON.stringify({'catalogGeneric' : description_data , 'tableName' : "fadsf"}),
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    }
});
```